# Open multiple website in a single window in different tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, browser

I want to open no. of urls and I want to open 1st url in new window and after that others in same window but in new tabs.
I am using c# and its a window application 
I use a code provided by Firefox but it is not opening new tab. It opens new window.
here is my code:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Process.Start("http://google.co.in","2048");
     Process.Start("http://google.co.in","2048");
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem starts when you don't have you're browser open.
Else it would work perfect without the Thread.Sleep.

Maybe you can try it like this

The "_blank" Opens a new blank page in the same window "So a new tab"

using System.Threading;

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Process.Start("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
    }
```

Comment: i wanna ask you 1 more thing that how to setup parameter in a URL and shoot it up one by one. if u have any sample code please share it. Thanks alot for help.

Comment: Better make a new question for that. Don't understand what you are asking , Sorry. Maybe if I got some more info or explanation.